# Hibernate criteria, selecting from entity A where someId in B

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Given entity classes:

```
class A { String name ... } 
class B { @OneToOne A a = ... ;  String gender; ... }
```

I am able to create a hibernate criteria and query it and all of it's associations.

However, B is not referenced from A at all. It's populated in a separate fashion and I would like to keep it as such.

Is there a way to perform a hibernate **criteria** query on A, and say, where this also is in B's relation, or where it is in B's relation and some field in B is this and that?

Here is some **non-working** pseudo code:

```
criteria(A.class).add(
        Restrictions.eq("name", "something")
).createAlias(
        B.class, "..."
).add(
        Restrictions.eq("gender", "Female")
);
```

**Note**, I would prefer not having to create a collection on A containing B's and using addAll.

I might **consider adding a dead reference** though, meaning something that is never intended to be accessed or updated but needed for hibernate to pull this off. It could be something like saying that this is maintained by another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery, as follows:

```
// create a 'DetachedCriteria' query for all the items in 'B'
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class).setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("propertyInB")) 
);

// then: search for A.id by adding 'dc' as asubquery:        
session.createCriteria(A.class).add(
    Subqueries.propertiesIn( new String[]{"propertyInA"}, dc)
).list();
```

This is roughly equivalent to: 'SELECT * FROM A a WHERE a.id in(SELECT id FROM B).

I hope my SQL is valid ;) .

See hibernate documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Great. I am going to test this. But do you know if DetachedCriteria are reusable, and thread safe? Could I possibly define a static final one and use elsewhere in a threaded environment? For instance the query you are doing here?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea

Comment: On second thought, all the DetachedCriteria is doing is storing instructions for doing a query without actually executing anything; afterwards, when you do a query in the session context, by calling the detached criteria you are executing it just like a regular criteria. Therefore, it would make sense to say that if a criteria is thread safe, so is a detached criteria, and vice versa.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Do you mind havin a look at this? I am getting exceptions, and I have tried a bunch of things. They are not matching id ( although I tried that as well, but on a unique field ticker that exists in both and have teh same values in both ): http://pastebin.com/RpWXvzVv

Comment: I edited your answer, it needs to be propertiesIn and an array passed. It just took me about four hours or so to debug myself to this point :( ... That's why methods should be named with the grouping denominator first. Subqueries.inProperties and I would have seen that there is another in method. in takes an object. One should also include the projectionsList in the detached query for in to work properly. I am not sure that will work otherwise as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77646/discussion-between-intellidata-and-momo).